# window.oper, window.addEventListener, window.attachEvent in conditional statement

Tags: javascript, dom, client-side

I'm having a hard time figuring out what those lines do. I'm following the tutorial below. My guess is that window.oper is mistyped and would be window.open. Open, addEventListener and attachEvent as far as I know are functions or methods not properties. Although I use Javascript a lot, I know very little.

```
if (window.oper || (!window.addEventListener && !window.attachEvent)) {
return false;
}
```

http://www.script-tutorials.com/custom-scrollbars-cross-browser-solution/

.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `window.oper` should be `window.opera`, which is an object that only exists (by default) in the Opera browser. The other clause is checking for the existence of either an `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` method of `window` and bailing out if neither exists. All major browsers released in the last 15 years support one or the other so that is intended to weed out really old browsers such as IE 4.